# Salesforce OM to capture payment is running under which user or permission set

Tags: apex, integration

I'm using Salesforce Order Management and i created a payment gateway provider to process payments and has provided a payment gateway adapter apex class.

I'm trying to save logs to a custom object, and whenever i do so the process fails without showing an error message. I'm doubting this has a relation todo with permission sets or user profile.

I would like to know the class will run under which user and will use which permission set

Comment: I tried to update the "Order Management B2C Service" permission set which is used for integration between Salesforce OMS and Commerce Cloud but its still not working

Comment: The flow runs under the automated process user.
I cannot modify the permissions access of that object

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add clarifications, rather than comments.

Comment: I found a solution:
The flow runs under the automated process user, so i created a permission set and assigned it to the user.
The other limitation is that with the current context of payment the DML giverner limits is 0, so you cannot insert or update records